# draw a number of squares for a given number

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, data-visualization

I'm trying to make a small widget based on a number (0, 1, 2 to 9).
It will be used in a `<td>` of a `<tr>`, in a table.

The solution i got so far is like this:

**JSFiddle**: 
https://jsfiddle.net/jeffxiao/c0ojm3wr/

([may not work](http://www.bootply.com/DbNNHDzMqh))

The issues are:

- no box shown when number = 0
- there is too much space between the boxes.

**Question**: Is there an easy way / library i can use for such a widget?

I've also thought of making ten images (for number 0 to 9), but i'd rather not use this approach.

Comment: I clicked the link, looked for a script and couldn't find any. Can you type your code in here?

Comment: @blaze_125 i've updated with a jsfiddle. can you try it again?

Comment: Went to fiddle: HTML split contains HTML code(DIVs and SPANs) but, CSS and Javascript splits show no content. Bottom Right split(the results) shows 8 black squares.

Answer (score 0):

We don't know what a box is. Well, we do... but... not in your context. Short of more information on what you're actually trying to do(*a minimal code sample could help here*), this is all I can offer.

Edit:
We got info on what a box is in your context so here's updated code.

```
var aSpan = "<span style='background: black; margin: 2px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>"

makeBoxes(5);
function makeBoxes(Howmany)
{
  for(var i = 0; i < Howmany; i++)
    {
      document.getElementById("TheTD").innerHTML += aSpan;
    }
}
```

> no box shown when number = 0

What do you expect to print on screen when the requested number of box is 0? No box shown for 0 sounds about right to me. If you expect to print 1 box for 0, does that mean you intend on printing 2 boxes for 1, 3 for 2 and so on?

Comment: `We don't know what a box is. ` ... i mean it in the most basic meaning, a square (maybe filled with color). title updated to square

Comment: I think the updated code above does what you want. It prints `n` boxes side by side. In my test HTML page, `document.getElementById("TheTD")` is a table column cell. The size of the box itself, in this snippet, is driven by the number of `&nbsp;` present. The distance between the boxes is managed by `margin: 2px;` in the span style definition.